# Proof of Non-3-Connectedness Given Vertex of Degree at Most 2

Tags: graph-theory

Today, my professor at university gave us a problem to solve. We need to prove that if a connected graph G has at least 4 vertices and contains a vertex of degree at most 2, G cannot be 3-connected.

I understand that a graph is 3-connected if it has at least 4 vertices and remains connected even if we remove any two vertices. However, I am unsure how to proceed with this problem.

Can you kindly offer any guidance or help? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: You just need to exhibit à 2 vertex cut (triangle graph needs special treatment, because its a special case in the definition of $3$-connectedness)